# Is this authentication system insecure or not

Tags: encryption, aes, authentication, semantic-security

So I want to create a simple, fast and yet secure authentication in two steps for a PC - microcontroller communication.

The first step is a seed request, the second step is an authentication request.

The encryption that is being used is AES-128.

There should be a fixed key `k` with a length of 16 bytes.

Whenever a seed request is coming a random 16 bytes authentication message `m` should be generated and then be encrypted with `k` and sent back to the client as a seed `s`.

(NOTE: `E(k, m)` will always output the same `s`)

The seed `s` then should be decrypted with `k` by the client and then the original authentication message `m` should be sent to the server as an authentication request.

The server compares the auth message `m` with the message of the request, and grants access if they are equal or rejects the request otherwise.

Also assume that an adversary can collect as many `m` and `s` pairs as he wants.

Based on the information above is it feasible to easily break this system or not?

Comment: Authentication is nice, but what are you going to do afterwards? How do you know that you are communicating with the right party? Don't you need to establish a secret? Or dual authentication? PS removed previous answer, shouldn't be answering  in the morning.

Comment: Consider it as a one to one communication, and after a successful auth you can access higher level functions of the controller, like modifying expert parameters and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It is vulnerable to replay attacks since the attacker knows the plaintext and its corresponding ciphertext. To mitigate against this you might want to include some information in the message like a timestamp so that assuming time keeping isn't compromised for the server and client, outdated messages, i.e messages marked by a timestamp earlier than a certain timeframe can be invalidated.

Comment: I don't think replay attack is an efficient approach here, because there are 2^128 `(s, m)` pairs. So the probability you get a seed that was already sent before is really low.

Comment: Ah i did not realize m is 16 bytes long and picked at random. I think you're right that a replay attack is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

No. This authentication scheme is secure. What this means is that when the protocol is done (server checks `m = m'`), the server can be sure that—some time before—an authentication request has been done by a party that knows `k`.

What you do after the authentication step may not be secure however. You should not forget to also authenticate *every message* in the conversation.

Comment: Excuse me but what happens if the attacker intercepts the message $m'$ and forward it ?
How can I make this scheme secure over the "Internet"?